# Is it good practice to not filter values according to nullability?

Tags: design-patterns, api, interfaces, null

Sometimes when I create an API that should enable getting a single value or all values I use the following pattern (passing `NULL` to the API, means get all rows):

@Usernames - comma separeted list of users

```
CREATE PROC GetUsers (@Usernames VARCHAR(100) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Users
    Where @Usernames IS NULL OR dbo.in_list(@Usernames,Username) = 1 
END
```

Is this a good practice to use the OR condition the get both functionalities, or should i write something like this:

```
CREATE PROC GetUsers (@Usernames VARCHAR(100) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Username IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM Users
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM Users
        Where dbo.in_list(@Usernames,Username) = 1 
    END
END
```

***Note:** 
This is only SQL for example, **this is not a specific coding language question**.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you allow `NULL` in the first place?

Comment: I'm allowing NULL's, so the user can get all the rows if he wants

Comment: Please clarify your comment regarding SQL only as an example.  Are you asking about "option 1" of individual operations when there is a conditional versus "option 2" of using a combined operation that accounts for the conditional?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title is different from the question within your posting, so I try to answer both questions.

IMHO it is a perfectly valid idiom to have a function with an optional filter condition, and when you leave that filter out, you get the full unfiltered result set. That's true for SQL as well as for many other programming languages.

As for which implementation is better: your first one is more comprehensive with less repetition of the same code (`SELECT * FROM Users`) and less boilerplate code (`IF .. END ELSE ...`) - so in general I would prefer this, since it is clearly better maintainable. Only if you suffer from an unexpected loss of performance you may test if the second alternative is faster. That will probably depend on your database system (maybe on the version), so do this only if you are 100% sure that it will be worth the hussle.

Answer (score 2):

Create another procedure named `GetEmployeesDetails`.

Your procedure is named `GetEmployeeDetails`, so the procedure should only do one thing: get the details of an employee.

You're making it do other things than what its name says if it returns something else than the details of *one* employee.

What's usually done is having a `GetEmployeesDetails` taking a `filter` parameter. This filter can be a hashmap, empty or not.

This is important not to do it your way; your procedure's name is misleading.

Comment: This is really not the main point here.

Comment: @Yosi Edited my answer.

Comment: You picked the most non important piece of the code and said something true about it.. but still this is far from answering what I asked. Now the name describes exactly what it does

Comment: @Yosi That isn't how answers work around here.  Answers should only be removed if the author makes no attempt to answer the question in his/her own words.  A wrong answer is still an answer, so if you disagree with it then you should vote it down.  Quality answers will rise to the top, poor answers will fall to the bottom.

Comment: @Yosi you edited your question to basically do what my answer says you should do.

Comment: No, there are two options there, the question asks about what is preferred and when.naming is important but it's not the main focus in the question and it is in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In application programming languages, I agree with Doc Brown. Nothing wrong here.

For the SQL implementation, parameter sniffing could create some havoc here. Consult an skilled DBA or read some serious papers on dynamic searching on your db engine of choice for better decision making.